# Programming python Matrix with 2D recursions

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to do a 2D band structure calculation which involves plane waves in multiple directions.  For a simple square system, I have 2 possible directions, and  couple terms that have {n,m} to either: {n,m},{n+1,m+1},{n+1,m-1},{n-1,m-1},{n-1,m+1},{n-2,m},{n+2,m},{n,m+2},{n,m-2}.

I am trying to figure out how to make an array that will make this.  I am not sure how to define some sort of basis.  In my case, I can cut off at some arbitrary max n,m and the dimension of of matrix will be (2n(max)+1)(2m(max)+1) since I want to run from -max to +max.

So essentially, I am trying to code a matrix M_ij that would give me the coupling between ij and i and j where i and j are some of those {n,m} combination.

Hopefully this makes sense.  Fun task for my first python experience.

Comment: What is not working with your approach?

Comment: I think I am lost on ordering and if I can just try making a giant grid that would then be able to do some kind of kronicker delta function....

Answer (score 0):

```
numpy.zeros(2n+1,2m+1)
```

Would get you the desired matrix of size.

You would then need to re-center the matrix in calculation by offsetting, e.g. `(x,y)` in normal would be `(x+n, y+m)`

Comment: So I actually need np.zeros(((2*n+1)**2,(2*m+1)**2))

But I do not see how that makes it simpler to calculate it